# Convert non-standard yml localization files to php array or other format usable for web translation

Tags: yaml, translation, transifex, stellaris

I tried to translate online with Transifex Stellaris localization files but it doesn't import it correctly because they don't follow localization standard:
http://docs.transifex.com/formats/yaml/

Here for example there is one file:
http://pastebin.com/abKLLSpX

I tried to convert it to php array or other formats usable on Transifex with some online (and offline) tools/scripts but i didn't find anything that convert it  without an error, here for example with Symfony it gave me the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException' with message 'Unable to parse at line 8 (near "DERELICT_SHIP_PROJECT:0 "Derelict Ship"").' in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Parser.php:246
```

Can someone give me an advice on how to convert it correctly to a format usable in Transifex please?

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

The file you linked contains lines like

```
DERELICT_SHIP_PROJECT:0 "Derelict Ship"
```

You probably want it to be a key-value pair:

```
DERELICT_SHIP_PROJECT: "Derelict Ship"
```

I don't know what the 0 is for and how it got there, but if you delete it from every line, you'll have a proper YAML source.